# Pyglet - TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python-2.7, pyglet, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to use pyglet instead of pygame, 'cause it supports several screens.
this is a sample code that I run:

```
import pyglet

display = pyglet.canvas.get_display()
screens = display.get_screens()
window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=True, screen=screens[1])

pyglet.app.run()
```

and I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/netcomShopTV/idk.py", line 5, in 
>       window = pyglet.window.Window()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/**init**.py", line 359,
>   in **getattr**
>       **import**(import_name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/**init**.py",
>   line 1890, in 
>       gl._create_shadow_window()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/gl/**init**.py", line
>   209, in _create_shadow_window
>       _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/**init**.py",
>   line 171, in **init**
>       super(XlibWindow, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/**init**.py",
>   line 642, in **init**
>       self._create()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/**init**.py",
>   line 265, in _create
>       self.context.set_vsync(self._vsync) # XXX ?   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py", line 265,
>   in set_vsync
>       warnings.warn(e) TypeError: expected string or buffer

Pyglet Version: 1.4.8

I searched in internet, couldn't find anything to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this bug was introduced with [this recent change](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/commit/f1f1861d9bc85bd497a2bb4f91dce39d2a0b968a#diff-08170116de16a52cd986c45ed70ab564). You should definitely raise it on `pyglet` github issue tracker.

Meanwhile, try installing the version prior to 1.4.8. (I though suspect this may just lead to crashing on failed sync as opposed to trying to warn you and then crashing :)).

Answer (score 0):

As @alecxe mentioned, it was a bug. After I opened a ticket on [github](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/issues/104), I got the solution:

> This is an exception for a Raspberry Pi specific issue. It's supposed
>   to raise a warning, and pass without crashing. If possible, could you
>   try editing line 265 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py, and
>   changing:
>
> warnings.warn(e) to warnings.warn(e.message)